# Efficiently read file line-by-line in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have already learned that [readline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline) can be used to read the file line by line, e.g.

```
readline
    .createInterface({input: fs.createReadStream('xxx')})
    .on('line', (line) => { apply_regexp_on_line })
    .on('close', () => { report_all_regexps });
```

However, this is pretty slow, since I compared the performance of `grep` and JavaScript regexp, and the latter has better performance on the regexps I tested. (see [benchmark](https://github.com/xis19/regexp_benchmark)) So I think I have to blame the node async readline.

In my situation, I do not care async at all, I just need to exploit the fast regexp from JavaScript to process very large log files (typically 1-2GB, sometimes up to 10GB). What is the best way of doing this? My only concern is speed.

Bonus points: some of the log files are gzipped, so I need to uncompress them. If someone can recommend me a fast line-by-line reader for both plain text and gzipped text exists, I would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what `apply_regexp_on_line` do but is it possible to use the unix `sed` program to do your string replacements? It is pretty quick. Probably can write a quick and easy shell script to do the unzipping and sed'ing.

Comment: Please see the benchmark link in the question. `sed` is not as fast as JavaScript. Basically `apply_regexp_on_line` would capture some text in the log file using regexp and store it, and `report_all_regexps` would report the captured text in a given format.

Comment: thanks for the information. Wasn't expecting `sed` to be slower than javascript's regex! up voted topic && added to favourite. I'm keen to know the solution too.

Comment: Hm, the benchmark that you posted doesn't seem correct, at least for the JS version. Can you measure in your case what is actually slow?

Comment: Wait, does your benchmark start a new `sed` for every test?

Comment: @robertklep unfortunately yes. however it won't explain why it is much slower than `grep`.

Comment: @xis and you're sure that you're not also timing the forking of a new process in your benchmarks? `sed` and `grep` will really be (much) faster than JS if you take into account that files have to be read and output has to be generated. It's almost impossible to do a fair comparison if your JS test doesn't time the I/O part (which it looks like it doesn't: it reads the data into memory and runs the benchmark against that).

Comment: @robertklep I wish I could bypass the forking and the reading of files. But the problem is I could not directly go into grep and benchmark the regexp match code. And async IO is rather slow in JS when you are working on local file.

Comment: Just take your real file and do the job in Node and with sed\grep and compare the time it takes to execute

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I just did that, but with a less sized log file, only 128MB, since my benchmark code is using JavaScript buffer, with a 192MB limitation. grep took 0.41 second and node took 0.32 second. I am counting the time using `/usr/bin/time` rather than my code. My regexp is `boot\.([a-z]+)_head\.`, both have 57654 captures.

Comment: @SamuelToh Please see Tomalak 's answer. At least we made the performance same to grep now.

Comment: @xis - thanks for letting me know. Sounds like I have something to play with over the weekend :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this hold up against your data?

```
// module linegrep.js
'use strict';
var through2 = require('through2');
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder

function grep(regex) {
    var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8'),
        last = "",
        lineEnd = /\r?\n/;

    var stream = through2({}, function transform(chunk, enc, cb) {
        var lines = decoder.write(last + chunk).split(lineEnd), i;
        last = lines.pop();
        for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (regex.test(lines[i])) this.push(lines[i]);
        }
        cb();
    }, function flush(cb) {
        if (regex.test(last)) this.push(last);
        cb();
    });
    stream._readableState.objectMode = true;
    return stream;
}

module.exports = grep;
```

and

```
// index.js

'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var grep = require('./linegrep');

function grepFile(filename, regex) {
    var rstream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {highWaterMark: 172 * 1024});
    if (/\.gz$/.test(filename)) rstream = rstream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
    return rstream
        .pipe(grep(regex));
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

var t = Date.now(), mc = 0;
grepFile('input.txt', /boot\.([a-z]+)_head\./).on('data', function (line) {
    mc++;
    console.log(line);
}).on('end', function () {
    console.log( mc + " matches, " + (Date.now() - t) + " ms" );
});
```

This turns a file stream into an object stream of lines, maps them through your regex and returns only the matching lines.

Comment: Slower than my code which uses `fs.readFileSync(filename).toString().split('\n').forEach((line) => { regexp.exec(/regexp/); });`

Comment: Hm, that's a shame. On the plus side, it can deal with arbitrarily large input files.

Comment: Well, that's correct. I am guessing that `node` event system is the reason why it is slow. Bypassing the event would make code much faster.

Comment: `split2()` might be slow here, too. Haven't looked at its source. But in any case, this is a bit more administrative overhead than doing basic string operations on a block of string that is entirely in memory.

Comment: Forget to mention benchmark data: it took ~1.2seconds while grep took 0.42 second and the toString code used 0.32 second.

Comment: @xis try again, I have shaved off a few milliseconds. Chances are that compiled, highly optimized tools like grep are still faster. Play around with the `highWaterMark` to determine the optimal buffer size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116000/discussion-between-xis-and-tomalak).

Comment: This is much faster, same performance to egrep, both 3.1 seconds (I am using another file/computer so the result can be different)

Comment: Good to hear! :) I guess depending on what you do/what output you want there are further ways to optimize, but I guess most time now goes into running the regex itself.

Comment: Obviously I misblamed the node event system :)

Comment: Well, essentially you were not wrong. I did remove quite a bit of event passing by fusing the multiple pipes (split->map->filter) of my first approach into one. I also rewrote the split code (originally from the split2 npm module), optimizing it a bit in the process. I guess there still is a small inefficiency in the handling of `last` in the above code, if you want try to make that bit smarter, maybe it helps you gain another few ms.

Comment: @xis Oh, and not decoding the input as utf8 also has an impact. If the logfile uses a single-byte encoding, configure the code accordingly. Of course you risk mangling the data if you make wrong assumptions here.

Comment: Replacing /\r?\n/ by '\n' improved the performance further, just fyi. I am sure I am using UNIX newline.

Comment: @xis Of course. It did not make much of a difference in my cursory tests, but maybe my inputs were too small. The largest file I tested it with was around 20 MB.